# Como listar eventos disponíveis em um elemento no IE8?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8, shim, polyfill

Estou fazendo um shim/polyfill para trabalhar com `CustomEvents` para IE8, mas estou tendo um problema para detectar quando o evento não é padrão.

No IE8 cada elemento pode ter uma lista diferente de eventos disponíveis, não existe a possibilidade de executar um `attachEvent` que não seja de um evento disponível por padrão no elemento.

No depurador do IE8, quando a gente aplica um *watch* no contexto do elemento (`this` em um método do elemento) ele mostra um objeto lista `[Events]` o qual contém os eventos disponíveis do mesmo.

O problema é que eu não consigo acessar esta propriedade sem ser pelo depurador.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como posso acessar essa propriedade de lista, ou existe alguma outra maneira de descobrir quais eventos estão disponível no contexto do elemento?

Comment: Não tenho IE8 pra testar agora, mas tentou `Element.prototype.on...`? Ou com um subtipo de `Element`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Descobri, na realidade o IE8 ele apenas faz uma lista no depurador das propriedades por ele reconhecidas como evento, porém estas estão todas como propriedades do próprio contexto do objeto.

Então para listar os eventos disponível da pra fazer assim:

```
var eventos = [];
for (var prop in this) if (prop.indexOf('on' === 0) {
    eventos.push(prop);
}
```

No caso acima `this` (o contexto) é um elemento HTML pois esse código estaria sendo executado dentro de um método deste elemento. Mas também funciona passando a referencia do elemento no lugar do contexto (`this`).

Para descobrir se o evento pertence ao elemento da pra fazer assim:

```
if ('onload' in this) {
    /* onload pertence a este elemento do contexto */
}
```

Comment: Algumas propriedades, incluindo alguns eventos, estão no prototype.

Comment: @bfavaretto sim, todas estão no protótipo, mas eu queria mesmo achar do elemento especifico, pois dependendo da herança dos protótipos vão existir diferentes eventos para o elemento. Mas agradeço a lembrança.